# Typescript Object is of type unknown

Tags: node.js, typescript

How to define the data type of **value** in the nodejs function written in typescript, so that **error of Object is of type unknow can be solved  ?**

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to answer this with the given information because it depends on the type of `res.get()`. Of you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the relevant code in you _as text_ then we can help you much better with this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement type for value. Try smth like this:

```
type valueType = {
  id: string,
  field1: number,
  field2: string,
}

const obj = {
  a: {
    id: '12',
    field1: 1,
    field2: 'asdas',
  }
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  const typedValue: valueType = value;
}
```